# Netbeans causing my logo to have inverted colors?

Tags: java, image, swing, user-interface, netbeans

I'm using Netbeans guibuilder and its working fine, however when I use the design preview button it changes the color of my logo for seemingly no reason. Anyone know how to fix this? I would post a screenshot, but I don't have enough rep to do so.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Post a link to an image of your screen shot that you've uploaded to an image sharing service (remember, the link should be to the uploaded *image*, not the *webpage*). We'll then be able to edit your question and show the image for you.

Comment: What type of image is it, jpg or png?

Comment: I just assigned it to a Labels Icon-Property and it is displayed correctly in preview. Which control did you use?

Comment: It's a png image. I'm using it as an icon for a Jlabel

Comment: It doesn't look inverted since the gradient is that same with the top of the letters lighter than the bottom. It looks like the red is "bleeding" outside the bird. I wonder if the image file is corrupted/out-of-spec and different libraries are "correcting" it differently.

Comment: The image displays fine on the forum so it should display fine on your frame. Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Transparency maybe? Set the label's backgroumd to white, and opaque to true.

Comment: Shows just fine here when displayed by a `JLabel` in a GUI launched from Netbeans.  Like advised by @camickr - post an SSCCE or [mcve].

Comment: If I type the code out myself it works, but when I make it using the Netbeans builder it always shows in red no matter what I do.

Comment: Tip: Add @HovercraftFullOfEels (or whoever, the `@` is important) to notify the person of a new comment.  *"If I type the code out myself it works, but when I make it using the Netbeans builder it always shows in red no matter what I do."* Then I guess the solution is not to rely on the tool (the IDE) that you clearly don't understand.  But then I don't offer support for IDEs, so there might be a way of changing that or a lack of understanding on your part (e.g. it is only 'red' in the builder, rather than the normally launched app.) - color me not caring either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your label inside a JPanel and set the background property of the JPanel to the color you want. An easy way to put a label into a JPanel is to select it, right-click and use the pop-up menu Enclose In -> Swing Containers -> Panel. Right-click on the JPanel for the pop-up properties or just select it and find properties on under the pallet on the right. The background colors for labels can change depending on the look and feel which can explain why it looks different in the preview than when you run or in the designer. You can also right-click the frame for "Preview Design in" pop-up menu option to preview in different look and feels.